# Internally distribute a Visual Studio Template using Nuget and SVN

Tags: visual-studio, svn, nuget

Suppose we have a Visual Studio template that we would like to distribute within our organization.  This template is hosted on an SVN server.  I would like users to be able to point Nuget to the SVN location and get the template installed in the proper location just like any other package.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this possible?

**We can do it but individuals do NOT recommend it.**

- **How**

  According to the [NuGet document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/what-is-nuget):

  > Put simply, **a NuGet package is a single ZIP file with the .nupkg
  >   extension** that contains compiled code (DLLs), other files related to
  >   that code, and a descriptive manifest that includes information like
  >   the package's version number. Developers with code to share create
  >   packages and publish them to a public or private host. Package
  >   consumers obtain those packages from suitable hosts, add them to their
  >   projects, and then call a package's functionality in their project
  >   code. NuGet itself then handles all of the intermediate details.

  **However**, the Visual Studio Template is a file with the `.zip` extension, which could not be recognized by NuGet. Even if we point NuGet to the SVN location, NuGet still can not recognize it.

  To resolve this issue, we have to create a NuGet package to include this Visual Studio Template `.zip` file, like:

  ```
  <files>
    <file src="TestDemo.zip" target="Tools\TestDemo.zip" />
  </files>
  ```

  Besides, there is another question, when we install this nuget package to the project, this Visual Studio Template `.zip` file would be downloaded to the `\packages` folder in the solution folder. We have to move it to the Visual Studio Templates folder.

  So, we have to add `.targets` with copy task in that nuget package to copy zip file to the Visual Studio Templates folder.

  The content of `.targets` file:

  ```
  <Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <Target Name="CopyTemplate" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="Copy Template to template folder."></Message>
    <Copy
    SourceFiles="$(SolutionDir)packages\MyTemplatePackage.1.0.0\Tools\TestDemo.zip"
    DestinationFolder="$(USERPROFILE)\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ProjectTemplates"
  />
    </Target>
  </Project>
  ```

  **Finally**, the `.nuspec` file like following:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <package >
    <metadata>
      <id>MyTemplatePackage</id>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <authors>Tester</authors>
      <owners>Tester</owners>
      <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
      <description>Package description</description>
      <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
      <copyright>Copyright 2018</copyright>
      <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
    </metadata>

    <files>
      <file src="TestDemo.zip" target="Tools\TestDemo.zip" />
      <file src="MyTemplatePackage.targets" target="Build\MyTemplatePackage.targets" />
    </files>
  </package>
  ```

  Then pack this .nuspec file, add this nuget package to the SVN location, add the SVN location to the nuget package source, you can install this nuget package to the project, and build the project, Visual Studio will download that nuget package and copy `.zip` file to the Visual Studio Templates folder.

  I have created a sample test nuget package and it work fine on my side with Visual Studio 2017, you can test it on VS2017: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ai1sp_yvodHf2Vax7TzuC6HQUD5w
- **Why not recommend**

  Just as you can see above, it is not easy and simple to do this, we have to do a lot of things to create that nuget package. What`s more, in order to get the template we have to create a project and install that package and build the project. It pulls in too many extra operations. Besides, when you change anything in the template, you have to re-create this package and install it.

  Since this template is hosted on an SVN server, you can just check it to the Visual Studio template folder, this will be more effective.

Hope this complicated answer helps.